# Exchange admin center forward and prepend body

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, forwarding, mail-forwarding

I want to forward all incoming E-mails to my HubSpot CRM System. To achieve this I want to configure my Exchange Server to forward them.

Exchange Server seems to provide only a redirect rule and no forward rule. Unfortunately redirect does not work, as Hubspot only recognize forwarded emails.

I've found this in the Hubspot Docs.

[image]

I assume that my exchange server redirects the email to Hubspot, but Hubspot can't find the forwarded text block and so it can't match the email to a contact.

Is there any way to forward all emails and append a text block with the sender to the original message ?

Comment: The `---Forwarded---` Block originates from Outlook Client, not from Exchange. Have you tried to create an Outlook rule on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to forward all incoming emails include a forwarded text block to Hubspot? If so, you could create a new mailbox which is specified to get all incoming emails, then create a transport rule which is used to Cc these emails to the new mailbox, after that, you could create an Outlook rule for this "**Cc**" mailbox to forward these incoming emails to Hubspot.

The following snapshots which show the transport/Outlook rule:

1.1 **Exchange 2010**(**Transport Rule**):
[image]

1.2 **Exchange 2013/2016/2019**(**Transport Rule**):
[image]

2. **Outlook Rule**:

[image]

After creating the above transport/outlook rules, all incoming emails will be Cc to the new mailbox, at the same time, they will be forwarded to another external email address :
[image]

Comment: This looks good. But does this work for a accounts for the whole company ?

Comment: Yep, the step 1.1 and 1.2 are to copy all incoming or outgoing emails in your organization  to a specific mailbox, and then we could use this mailbox to forward emails to Hubspot(The forwarded emails also include the forwarded text block).

Comment: Does it work even if my outlook is closed ?

Comment: @SimonLudwig You could check if the rule only applies for Outlook, or both of Outlook and OWA by viewing if there is a status "Client-Only" behind the rule. If the rule shows "Client-Only" status, the rule won't work until you start Outlook. For the rule I post above, it will work even Outlook is closed